# How to Create cookie data from dictionary - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, session, cookies

```
{'full_name': 'Test%20User', 'sid': '09a5de5792d5ad465d4bd0ab0986618e834f09d6af79dba608420efe', 'system_user': 'yes', 'user_id': 'test.user%40example.com', 'user_image': ''}
```

i want to convert the above dictionary format into below cookie format

```
'full_name=Test%20User; sid=7f25bb3a8129f4369c22f43bde382328089df64af77bd0200f9550d9; system_user=yes; user_id=test.user%40example.com; user_image='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `.join` twice with a list comprehension, once to join the dict items with `=`, and another to join the list with `;`  (note the space)

```
d = {'full_name': 'Test%20User', 'sid': '09a5de5792d5ad465d4bd0ab0986618e834f09d6af79dba608420efe', 'system_user': 'yes', 'user_id': 'test.user%40example.com', 'user_image': ''}

"; ".join(["=".join(x) for x in d.items()])

'full_name=Test%20User; sid=09a5de5792d5ad465d4bd0ab0986618e834f09d6af79dba608420efe; system_user=yes; user_id=test.user%40example.com; user_image='
```